# charsets problems with php

Tags: php, character-encoding

we are aproblems with codification in php, we are web site www.toroalbala.com and select rusian lenguage and is imposible to read caracter, we use a comun.php for all web, this is the codification, but when i change to tf8, i can read corect caracter in spanish-french

Toro Albalá

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">     
    <?PHP if ((($_REQUEST["seccion"] == "distribuidores") || ($_REQUEST["seccion"] == "admin")) && (isset($_REQUEST["salir"]))) { echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;URL=comun.php?seccion=inicio&amp;idioma=".$_SESSION["idioma"]."'>"; } ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo/estilo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_comun.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/errores.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    registraScroll(
    'bajar',
    'subir',
    'galeria',
    10,
    -10)
    </script>

    <!-- Hoja de estilo y JavaScript exclusivos para sIFR (SustituciÃ³n de encabezados por Flash) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo/sifr.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sifr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sifr-config.js"></script>

    <!-- Estilos Ãºnicos para versiones antiguas de IE -->
    <!--[if IE 7]>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo/estilo_ie7.css" type="text/css"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo/estilo_ie6.css" type="text/css"><![endif]-->

    <!-- Script para Google Maps de "Contacto" -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAvn-oxW0rOOAb7BObXLASexSrW4t9k5QZjbduSj86SNxcQTpC7hT_3OF3z-8NC5jFJuEuEwGOoZ8jag" type="text/javascript"></script>

</HEAD>
<?PHP
    if ($_REQUEST["seccion"] == "contacto")
    {
        echo "<body onload='initialize()' onunload='GUnload()'>";
    }else
    {
        echo "<body>";
    }
    // Se comprueba si se a solicitado un cambio de idioma, y se aplica dicho cambio
    if ((isset($_REQUEST["idioma"])) && (($_REQUEST["idioma"] == "ENG") || ($_REQUEST["idioma"] == "ESP") || ($_REQUEST["idioma"] == "FRA") || ($_REQUEST["idioma"] == "ITA")|| ($_REQUEST["idioma"] == "RUS")))
    {
        $_SESSION["idioma"] = $_REQUEST["idioma"];
    }

    // El idioma por defecto serÃ¡ EspaÃ±ol. En caso de no encontrarse asignado se asignarÃ¡ por defecto
    if (!isset ($_SESSION["idioma"]))
    {
        $_SESSION["idioma"] = "ESP";
    }

    // Se incluye el fichero de idioma segÃºn el escogido
    switch ($_SESSION["idioma"])
    {
        case "ENG":
            include ("idioma/english.php");
            break;
        case "ESP":
            include ("idioma/espanol.php");
            break;
        case "FRA":
            include ("idioma/french.php");
            break;
        case "ITA":
            include ("idioma/italiano.php");
            break;
        case "RUS":
            include ("idioma/ruso.php");
            break;

    }

    // Generamos una URL para el cambio de idioma cumpliendo con los estÃ¡ndares (ampersand) y evitando la duplicaciÃ³n de variables
    $URL_div = split ("&", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $URL = $URL_div[0];
    for ($contador1 = 1; $contador1 < count($URL_div); $contador1++)
    {
        if ($URL_div[$contador1] != "idioma=".$_REQUEST["idioma"]."")
        {
            $URL = $URL."&amp;".$URL_div[$contador1];
        }
    }
?>
<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="menu_sup"><a href="comun.php?seccion=inicio"><?PHP echo constant("_INICIO"); ?></a> 
    <?PHP 
        if ($_SESSION["idioma"] != "ENG"){ echo "<a href='".$URL."&amp;idioma=ENG'><img class='bandera_mini' alt='English' src='imagenes/estructura/ENG.png'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";} 
        if ($_SESSION["idioma"] != "ESP"){ echo "<a href='".$URL."&amp;idioma=ESP'><img class='bandera_mini' alt='Espa&ntilde;ol' src='imagenes/estructura/ESP.png'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";}
        if ($_SESSION["idioma"] != "FRA"){ echo "<a href='".$URL."&amp;idioma=FRA'><img class='bandera_mini' alt='Fran&ccedil;ais' src='imagenes/estructura/FRA.png'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";}
        if ($_SESSION["idioma"] != "ITA"){ echo "<a href='".$URL."&amp;idioma=ITA'><img class='bandera_mini' alt='Italiano' src='imagenes/estructura/ITA.png'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";}
        if ($_SESSION["idioma"] != "RUS"){ echo "<a href='".$URL."&amp;idioma=RUS'><img class='bandera_mini' alt='Ruso' src='imagenes/estructura/RUS.png'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";}

    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="lateral">
        <div style="margin: 0px auto 35px auto;"><img style="max-width: 180px" src="imagenes/estructura/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/logotipo.gif" alt="Toro Albal&aacute;"></div>
        <div style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <div>
                <a href="comun.php?seccion=bodega&amp;pag=1" OnMouseOver="cambio('boton1', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');" OnMouseOut="volver('boton1', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');"><img class="menu" id="boton1" src="imagenes/botones/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/boton1_inicio.gif" alt="Nuestra bodega"></a>
                <a href="comun.php?seccion=vinos" OnMouseOver="cambio('boton2', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');" OnMouseOut="volver('boton2', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');"><img class="menu" id="boton2" src="imagenes/botones/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/boton2_inicio.gif" alt="Nuestros vinos"></a>
                <a href="comun.php?seccion=otros_productos" OnMouseOver="cambio('boton3', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');" OnMouseOut="volver('boton3', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');"><img class="menu" id="boton3" src="imagenes/botones/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/boton3_inicio.gif" alt="Otros productos"></a>
                <a href="comun.php?seccion=palmares" OnMouseOver="cambio('boton4', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');" OnMouseOut="volver('boton4', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');"><img class="menu" id="boton4" src="imagenes/botones/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/boton4_inicio.gif" alt="Palmar&eacute;s"></a>
                <a href="comun.php?seccion=gastronomia" OnMouseOver="cambio('boton5', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');" OnMouseOut="volver('boton5', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');"><img class="menu" id="boton5" src="imagenes/botones/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/boton5_inicio.gif" alt="Gastronom&iacute;a"></a>
                <a href="comun.php?seccion=prensa" OnMouseOver="cambio('boton6', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');" OnMouseOut="volver('boton6', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');"><img class="menu" id="boton6" src="imagenes/botones/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/boton6_inicio.gif" alt="Prensa"></a>
                <a href="comun.php?seccion=visita_virtual" OnMouseOver="cambio('boton7', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');" OnMouseOut="volver('boton7', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');"><img class="menu" id="boton7" src="imagenes/botones/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/boton7_inicio.gif" alt="Visita virtual"></a>
                <a href="comun.php?seccion=contacto" OnMouseOver="cambio('boton8', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');" OnMouseOut="volver('boton8', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');"><img class="menu" id="boton8" src="imagenes/botones/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/boton8_inicio.gif" alt="Contacto"></a>
                <div style="margin:10px;"><a href="comun.php?seccion=distribuidores" OnMouseOver="cambio('boton9', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');" OnMouseOut="volver('boton9', '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>');"><img style="border-width: 0;" id="boton9" src="imagenes/botones/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["idioma"]; ?>/boton9_inicio.gif" alt="Distribuidores"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenido"><?PHP include ($_REQUEST["seccion"].".php"); ?></div>
    <?PHP include ("copyright.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure your php files are saved as UTF-8 and additionally you can add following;

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Of course don't forget to add meta (:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: meta is optional when serving the files from a server because http headers preveil but this is indeed a good idea not to keep a meta says iso while the headers say utf8 ;-)

Comment: Well, no matter if I will add PHP headers or not, I will still define meta charset in my html pages. I used to this and I will always use it (: